# Reading/writing Device Name characteristic of BLE Device in iOS 7

Tags: ios

I want to rename the device name of BLE Device. In iOS 6.1.3, I am able to write the "Device Name" Characteristic of Generic Access Profile Service. But in iOS 7 and later, CBPeripheral is unable to discover the Generic Access Profile Service(1800).

My Question is that Is it possible to read/write Device Name characteristic of BLE Device in iOS 7? If it is possible, then how can I do that? If apple has removed this support in iOS7 and greater, then what is alternate to do this?

Comment: My understanding is that it is no longer possible. But why do you need to change the device name anyway? You can always include your own arbitrary information in the service UUID which can likely substitute what you were using the device name for

Comment: Thanks @BrockAmhurst for quick feedback. Actually, It is an important functionality of my app from client. Thats why I want to rename the device name characteristic

Answer (score 2):

iOS prevents that Service from being usable by a developer. Section 3.12 (page 24) documents the fact iOS does not let a developer use that Service (and a couple others) https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf

I ended up making a custom Characteristic that an app could write to. The firmware would handle that write request and then update the device name and advertising packet. It's seems hacky, but I wasn't able to find a better solution. It's unfortunate that iOS blocks this because it makes it impossible to make a device that is compatible with other apps unless someone makes a separate 'custom device name' standard or something...